# in Postgres, while calling INSTR function in another trigger function giving error

Tags: postgresql

I got an INSTR function from this group, when I try to use that in my another trigger function, it is giving me the following error:

An error has occurred:

> ERROR:  function instr(character varying, character varying, integer,
>   numeric) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
>   instrbals(NEW.result_data,v_sample_seperator,1,n_samp...
>                  ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. QUERY: 
>   SELECT instrbals(NEW.result_data,v_sample_seperator,1,n_sample_counter
>   + 1) > 0 CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function upd_lab_test_results() line 49 at WHILE

Comment: _this group_, which group ?

Comment: Could you attache description of the function and the trigger? Insert query also can be helpful.

Comment: following re the minimal details nw in function...function is also attached.         select instrbals(;&
217011802;217011802;;
885;;F;F;10/01/2017 13:46:17;5.5100;;mmol/L;;0;;;;,;,1,2+1)          ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: select instrbals(;&
                         ^

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the complete code that calls the function. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)